# I already have the log file. How can I make a graph of it?

Tags: charts, log4j, graph, perf4j

I already have log file. Now what i need is to make the graph of that log file.
Is there any command line tool or google API to make graph which will show every transaction time.

Thank You

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the contents of your log file?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your file to Google Docs as a spreadsheet and then do charting & graphs out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
java -jar perf4j-0.9.13.jar /path/to/perf4jLog.log -t 86400000 -g out.html
```

Note here where i use `-t 86400000` which means collate the data via days. Use whatever is applicable for you.

My log4j.xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="perf4jLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param value="perf4jLog.log" name="File"/>
        <param value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" name="DatePattern"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="perf4jLog"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value ="INFO"/> 
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Now you can open up `out.html` and the images should load the chart from google.